# How to create beast's roar effect from recorded human voice?

Tags: effects, animals

I would like to create the beast roaring effect from a recorded human voice like in [this video](https://youtu.be/34cHO5_LX9g?t=107) (1m46s-1m49s). Is it possible to get a similar result generated from human speech? By which effect can I achieve the desired result?

I have tried to lower pitch, lower playback speed, reversing playback, but it is not even close to what i need. Speech is still recognized, but it shouldn't.

P.S.: I am not a sound designer at all, sorry if the question is dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a human voice to me - & 'movie roars' tend to be multi-layers of different sounds played at different speeds & pitches so they can't simply be identified as 'a lion' etc.

The simplest technique I know of for faking an animal roar using only the human voice is to roar into a pint glass.

A simple mechanical device can be made with an old drum (a tom-tom from a drum kit) & a piece of string/rope. There's a tutorial here - [Instructables.com, Creating a Lion's Roar](https://www.instructables.com/id/Creating-a-Lions-Roar/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I doubt it is not processed human voice. Unfortunately I need to generate roar based on speech. Seems like it is not possible. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very nice tool that can help you with this, check out https://www.krotosaudio.com/products/reformer/

You can feed pre-recorded audio into it, or shout into the mic itself. It's very easy and powerful to use in realtime!